# Have I Hashed and Salted Correctly?

Tags: python, cryptography, passwords, password-protection, password-hash

I am new to this, and I want to know if I've coded this correctly.

If so, how would I then go about storing the hashed password on a database?

```
import hashlib
import os

password = input("Create Password")

def hash_new_password(password):
     hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('blake2b', password.encode('utf-8'), salt=os.urandom(16), iterations=100000)
     return hash.hex()

hashed = hash_new_password(password)

print(hashed)
```

Comment: You’re only always hashing the same binary string `b'password'`. You’re not using the variable `password`.

Comment: When I run the variable password I get the error, "a-bytes - like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: To turn a string into a `bytes`, encode it: `password.encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 1):

No, for cryptography you should be using secrets and not `os.urandom` https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html .

And for the `hash_new_password` function, shouldn't you also return the salt so it can be stored so you can compare equality later?

Also obligatory "don't roll your own crypto"

Comment: Isn't the salt already part of my hash variable?

Comment: You will be needing the salt stored somewhere for a `check_if_correct_password` function. You'll have to store the salt and password hash for each user.